# How can I retrieve only those columns which contain 3 consective numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have columns in my dataframe such as:

```
['col1_103_diff','col2_105_diff','col_106_diff'...]
```

How can I use list comprehension to retrieve only those columns like above?

```
merged.filter(like='121_diff')
```

This works but I am not sure what regex I could use to define 3 numbers followed by a word

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` with regex, like below:

```
merged.filter(regex=r'\d{3}\w+')
```

The regex `\d{3}\w+` defines exactly 3 digits followed by a word:

`\d{3}`  exactly 3 occurrences of `\d` (digit)

`\w+`  a word with at least one character(s) in `A-Z`, `a-z` and `_` (underscore).